# What is an axe beak’s travel speed in Icewind Dale?

Tags: dnd-5e, animals, travel, rime-of-the-frostmaiden

*Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden* gives [overland travel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/welcome-to-the-far-north#OverlandTravel) speeds for dogsleds, snowshoes, and on foot (p. 11). On the same page, it says that dogsleds, at 1mph, are the fastest way to get around in the Dale.

However, this section says nothing about [axe beaks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/ten-towns#GettingAroundTenTowns), which p. 20 offers as a travel option. How fast would these travel?

My gut says if they are speedier than sled dogs (50 vs 40 feet per round, per MM), they might run 1.25 mph. Is this the best/proper way to calculate it?
How does this reconcile with sled dogs being the fastest travel method (p. 11)?
Do sled dog rest requirements (1 hour after an hour of pulling, p. 20) factor into the answer at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The book does not say, but 25% faster than a dog sled seems reasonable.

Unfortunately, the axe beak seems to have been passed over when discussing travel times of the various modes of transportation. But, we can make some reasonable estimates.

#### Sled Dogs

Dogsleds are described on page 20. A dogsled weighs 300 pounds, and one sled dog (use the [wolf](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/wolf) statblock) can pull 360 pounds. So we need 2 dogs per sled for a medium sized character. Two dogs pulling a medium character and a sled will travel at the usual pace of 1 mile per hour over land (pg. 11).

#### Axe Beaks

Now, axe beaks are not afforded the courtesy of having their overland travel speeds just given to us. Naturally, it would seem to make sense to just compare its listed speed to the listed speed of a sled dog (wolf). We just need to be sure we won't run into any issues of our axebeak becoming over encumbered. The axe beak description on page 20 says:

> An axe beak’s splayed toes allow it to run across snow, and it can carry as much weight as a mule.

Okay, so it can carry as much as a mule. Why do I have to do that math? Is Christopher Perkins the one writing the convoluted math word problems we all did in high school? Looking at the [mule](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mule) statblock, we see this feature:

> ***Beast of Burden***. The mule is considered to be a Large animal for the purpose of determining its carrying capacity.

Okay, so it counts as large, and it has a strength score of 14. From the rules on carrying capacity:

> Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry, which is high enough that most characters don't usually have to worry about it.
>
> Larger creatures can bear more weight, whereas Tiny creatures can carry less. For each size category above Medium, double the creature's carrying capacity and the amount it can push, drag, or lift. For a Tiny creature, halve these weights.

So the axebeak can comfortably carry 420 pounds - more than enough to carry a medium humanoid and their gear, *and exactly the pulling weight of two dogs pulling a sled*.

**This is the notable point**: Two dogs can pull 720 pounds, and a sled weighs 300 pounds, so two dogs pulling a sled can pull exactly 420 pounds of character, and an axe beak can pull exactly 420 pounds of character.

#### Conclusion

Two dogs and a sled can pull exactly the same amount of character as one axebeak. Therefore, it seems entirely reasonable that just comparing their listed speeds will be an apples-to-apples comparison. The wolf has a listed speed of 40 ft, the axebeak has a listed speed of 50 ft, so we conclude that the axe beak is 25% faster than two dogs pulling a dogsled.

#### Other Considerations

Page 11 does have the statement:

> The fastest way to travel across the tundra is by dogsled.

What do we do with this? I don't know. Ignore it? The poor axebeak seems to have been an after thought here, so it would not surprise me if this sentence was written before axebeak was even put in. It seems clear that the writers didn't think too hard about how fast an axebeak could move through tundra, so it would make sense if this statement didn't consider axebeaks at all.

Either way, it's your adventure. You decide. Unless you aren't the DM, then just buy a dogsled. As the introduction says:

> Nothing in this adventure is too sacred to tamper with and repurpose to serve your own needs.

#### Do they need to rest?

I need to rest. I'm exhausted from Christopher Perkins’ stablock-goose-chase of a math problem. I'd say they need to rest. If you want to be faithful to the adventure's apparent intention for the difficulty of overland travel, making axebeaks faster *and* making them not have to rest seems to be a little cheesy. *They're already way cheaper than the dogsled setup*.

Comment: The axebeak can _carry_ as much weight as a mule.  Is there anything that says it can _pull_?  PHB says "You can push, drag, or lift a weight in pounds up to twice your carrying Capacity (or 30 times your Strength score)."  Presumably IDRFM is using "pull" to mean "drag".  Is there anything in the book that indicates an axebeak can be harnessed to a sled?  Can have a pack harness?  Can be saddled and ridden?

Comment: Ask your DM. Or if you’re the DM, just make something up. *None of this is clearly laid out in the book*.

Comment: In my campaign, I have the dwarves running a sleigh by pulled by Axe-Beaks to Luskan every full moon to pick up vital supplies like wheat, barley, oats, and yeast. This gave some characters a means to travel to the Dale. It's kind of up to you as the DM, but using the weight and pulling rules you can make it work. I'm using the normal sled dog rules if there are only two dogs, but if they have a full team of like eight then I'm going to give them some extra speed and probably reduce the resting requirements a bit. In a traditional setup, the two dogs next to the sled do the most work.

Comment: @Kirt The rules are even more odd on this, PHB page 155: "An animal pulling a carriage, cart, chariot, sled, or wagon can move weight up to five times its base carrying capacity, including the weight of the vehicle. If multiple animals pull the same vehicle, they can add their carrying capacity together." Sled dog uses the wolf stat block, which has STR of 12, which is 180 lbs capacity, which should be 900 lbs pulling capacity (or 600 lbs + sled).

Comment: @Journer Yeah, the travel rules given in *Rime* are definitely inconsistent with the usual rules given in the PHB and DMG. If this question weren't about *Rime* specifically, the answer would be different.

Comment: @Journer Yes, the animal pulling was the more correct citation there, thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that dogs or axebeaks have better endurance? This might influence the answer.

Comment: @Tommi As far as I can tell, this answer covers all of the relevant material from the adventure.

Comment: Not sure where they get the dog sled weight of 300 lbs from. A real dogsled (traditional wooden construction, a "basket sled" for carrying loads) only weights about 100 lbs. 300 lbs would be the weight of the sled PLUS the person driving it. Unless the sled comes with a driver included???

Comment: @ErichJacoby-Hawkins I just noticed your comment. I think in this case, a sled is actually a sleigh. For a sled like the Iditirod, I would use the weight of the chariot (100 lbs). Though I would still use a price of 15 - 20 gp (cart or sled price).